# Search a JSON array in Oracle

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to use the new JSON features introduced in Oracle 12.1.0.2

However I can't seem to find a way to look for a specific value in an array inside my JSON document.

Consider the following table and data:

```
create table orders
(
   id      integer not null primary key,
   details clob not null check (details is json (strict))
);

insert into orders (id, details) values 
(1, '{"products": [{ "product": 1, "quantity": 5}, {"product": 2, "quantity": 1}], "delivery_address": "My hometown"}');

insert into orders (id, details) values 
(2, '{"products": [{ "product": 42, "quantity": 1}, {"product": 10, "quantity": 2}], "comment": "Your website is too slow"}');

insert into orders (id, details) values 
(3, '{"products": [{ "product": 543, "quantity": 1}], "discount": "15"}');

insert into orders (id, details) values 
(4, '{"products": [{ "product": 738, "quantity": 12}], "discount": "32"}');
```

Now I'm trying to write a SQL query that returns all orders, where product #2 was ordered.

I can't use [`json_exists`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions010.htm#SQLRF56664) because it doesn't allow array expressions (and I wouldn't know how to specify the value anyway).

[`json_value`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56668) only returns a single value, so I can't "iterate" over the array values.

I tried:

```
select *
from orders o
where json_value(details, '$.products[*].product') = '2';
```

but that didn't return anything.

I also tried [`json_table`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions091.htm#SQLRF56973), but that also seems to only take the first element from the array:

```
select *
from orders o, 
     json_table(o.details, '$' columns (product_id integer path '$.products[*].product')) t
where t.product_id = 2;
```

But that didn't show anything. Apparently the "star expansion" in the "[array_step](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56668)" doesn't expand the values in the `json_table`

So my question is:

how can I (based on the above sample data) retrieve all orders where the product with the number 2 has been ordered?

I am essentially looking for the  equivalent to this Postgres query:

```
select *
from orders
where details @> '{"products": [{"product": 2}] }';
```

Comment: We experienced a multi-threading bug when running the JSON_TABLE function. Basically, one of the sessions got disconnected when running two simultaneous JSON_TABLE. Make sure you have patched it before going all in with JSON.

Comment: @PeterHenell: thanks for the hint. Currently I'm just exploring the possibilities, but I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I do not have any installation of oracle available right now but I believe that the first string in json_table should be the path to the array which we want to produce rows from. 
Then inside *COLUMNS*, the path should be relative to the array, not the root.

Try this:

```
select *
from orders o, 
     json_table(o.details, '$.products[*]' 
         columns (
              product_id integer path '$.product'
         )
     ) t
where t.product_id = 2;
```

Comment: Can we update an existing array?
Can we add a product object to products array of the order with id 1?

Answer (score 0):

In 12.2 you can do this with JSON_EXISTS

```
 SQL> WITH ORDERS as
   2  (
   3    select 1 as ID, '{"products": [{ "product": 1, "quantity": 5}, {"product": 2, "quantity": 1}], "delivery_address": "My hometown"}' as DETAILS
   4      from dual
   5    union all
   6    select 2 as ID, '{"products": [{ "product": 42, "quantity": 1}, {"product": 10, "quantity": 2}], "comment": "Your website is too slow"}' as DETAILS
   7      from dual
   8    union all
   9    select 3 as ID, '{"products": [{ "product": 543, "quantity": 1}], "discount": "15"}' as DETAILS
  10      from dual
  11    union all
  12    select 4 as ID, '{"products": [{ "product": 738, "quantity": 12}], "discount": "32"}' as DETAILS
  13     from dual
  14  )
  15  select *
  16    from ORDERS
  17   where JSON_EXISTS(DETAILS,'$?(@.products.product == $PRODUCT)' passing 2 as "PRODUCT")
  18  /

         ID
 ----------
 DETAILS
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          1
 {"products": [{ "product": 1, "quantity": 5}, {"product": 2, "quantity": 1}], "d
 elivery_address": "My hometown"}


 SQL>
```

Comment: Actualy json_exist work in the same fasion in 12.1 but doen't use indexex